# How do I access my viewController from my appDelegate? swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I access my lable in viewController from my appDelegate in swift

thanks

Comment: generally, you don't. wanting to do so indicates an architecture error. explain why you need it...

Comment: It does not make sense to access var of VC in app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a recommended solution!
However, some developers, when in need to do so, set an observer in the view controller. the observer listens to a notification that can be sent from anywhere (including appDelegate). Once the notification is sent, a method is triggered in the view controller, so now you can change anything you want.